# Finding the number of 3-element subsets from the set {1,2,3,...,11,12,13} such that the sum of the 3 elements is divisible by 3

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

I found this problem from an old math questionnaire.

How many 3-element subsets of {1,2,3,...,11,12,13} are there for which the sum of the 3 elements is divisible by 3?

At first, I tried listing down all of them. But then, I realized they were too many and so, I just stopped. Next, I tried using stars and bars technique. I represented the 3 elements as a,b,c and their sum as a+b+c=m where m is the set of positive integers divisible by 3 from 3 to 39. From there, I tried out each equation with stars and bars from a+b+c=3 to a+b+c=15, and found a total of 185 subsets satisfying the given conditions. I stopped at here since I noticed that if I continued doing this from a+b+c=18 to a+b+c=39, I would have an error since I was not able to limit the values of a,b,c at most 13.

I do not know how to proceed right now. Can anyone help?

Comment: @Ross Millikan, Jack D' Aurizio and Batominovski, I really appreciate your help. Unfortunately, the solutions you suggested were honestly too much for me to handle. I really do not understand a single one you, guys, suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:  There are five elements of your set that are $1 \bmod 3$, four that are $0 \bmod 3$ and four that are $2 \bmod 3$.  You can get a sum that is $0 \bmod 3$ by taking three of the same kind or one of each kind.

Comment: but remember that you have to take them in order

Comment: @GCab:  we were asked for subsets, so order doesn't matter.

Comment: Oops, perhaps there is some misunderstanding: as far as I know sets and subsets are ordered lists, so in the present case one of the specified subsets would be for instance ${3,6,9}$, while ${6,3,9}$ is not a subset: am I wrong ?

Comment: @GCab:   No, sets are not ordered.  $\{6,3,9\}$ is a subset of the given set, but it is the same subset as $\{3,6,9\}$. It should only be counted once.

Comment: so.. I'm not native english speaker, but (probably) understood the "punctualization" you want to make about the concept of *set* and that's right .  However coming to counting, so in combinatorics at least, *subsets*  (understanding *different subsets*) bi-ject to *tuples* : can we say that?

Comment: @GCab:   No, subsets are sets and (as such) are not ordered.  If you want to specify the order you need a sequence or a tuple.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am honestly more interested in your hint than Jack and Batominovski's solutions. I think theirs are too advanced for my level. May I ask you to please continue your solution for I do not have the background of modulo operation.

Comment: modulo is just the remainder on division, so the ones that are $1 \bmod 3$ are $1,4,7,10,13$.  When you take the integers modulo anything you get a ring-you can add, subtract, multiply, and distribute multiplication over addition just like in the integers.  So the problem is asking you to choose three numbers whose sum is $0 \bmod 3$.  If you add three of the numbers that are $1 \bmod 3$ you get a total of $0 \bmod 3$, so choosing any three of these five will be a solution.  You can also choose three of the four that are $2 \bmod 3$, or three that are $0 \bmod 3$, or one of each because ...

Comment: $0+1+2 =0 \bmod 3$.  Now you just have to do the combinatorics.

Comment: I finally got it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

A more general approach is given by generating functions.
We may consider the bivariate polynomial

$$ q(x,y)=(1+yx)(1+yx^2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(1+yx^{12})(1+yx^{13}) $$
and the coefficient of $y^3$ in $q(x,y)$, that is
$$ [y^3]\,q(x,y) = r(x) = x^6+x^7+2 x^8+3 x^9+4 x^{10}+5 x^{11}+7 x^{12}+8 x^{13}+10 x^{14}+12 x^{15}+14 x^{16}+15 x^{17}+17 x^{18}+17 x^{19}+18 x^{20}+18 x^{21}+18 x^{22}+17 x^{23}+17 x^{24}+15 x^{25}+14 x^{26}+12 x^{27}+10 x^{28}+8 x^{29}+7 x^{30}+5 x^{31}+4 x^{32}+3 x^{33}+2 x^{34}+x^{35}+x^{36} $$
then sum the coefficients of the monomials of the form $x^{3k}$. If $\omega=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3}\right)$, that sum is just
$$ \frac{1}{3}\left( r(1)+r(\omega)+r(\omega^2) \right) $$
or the coefficient of $y^3$ in the polynomial $\frac{1}{3}\left(q(1,y)+q(\omega,y)+q(\omega^2, y)\right)$, where:

$$\frac{1}{3}\left(q(1,y)+q(\omega,y)+q(\omega^2, y)\right) = (1+y)^4\cdot\left(1+20 y^2+14 y^3+\ldots\right)$$
gives us the answer:
$$ 14+4\cdot 20+4 = \color{red}{98}. $$
Not by chance, this number is close to one third of the total number of $3$-subsets, given by $\binom{13}{3}=286$.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not have a background of generating functions. Is there any other solution that can be used? I believe that generating functions are too advanced for me.

Comment: @CarlTerenceValdellon: Ross Millikan already provided you an elementary solution: $$98=\binom{4}{3}+\binom{4}{3}+\binom{5}{3}+4\cdot 4\cdot 5.$$

Answer (score 1):

Jack D'Aurizio's answer can be generalized.  However, I don't think that the computation is simple.

> Let $m$, $n$, and $p$ be positive integers such that $m\leq n$.  The polynomial $f_{m,n}(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ is given by $$f_{m,n}(x,y):=\prod_{i=1}^n\,\left(1+xy^i\right)-1\,.$$
>   For any positive integer $s$, write $\omega_s:=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi\text{i}}{s}\right)$.  Then, the number of $m$-subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ whose sum is $k$ modulo $p$, where $k\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,p-1\}$, is given by
>   $$N_{m,n,p,k}:=\frac{1}{pn}\,\sum_{r=0}^{p-1}\,\omega_p^{-rk}\,\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\,\omega_n^{-jm}\,f_{m,n}\left(\omega_n^j,\omega_p^r\right)\right)\,.\tag{1}$$

Alternatively, let $$\tilde{f}_{m,n}(x,y):=\prod_{i=1}^n\,\left(1+xy^i\right)\,.$$  Then, 
$$N_{m,n,p,k}=\frac{1}{p(n+1)}\,\sum_{r=0}^{p-1}\,\omega_p^{-rk}\,\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n}\,\omega_{n+1}^{-jm}\,\tilde{f}_{m,n}\left(\omega_{n+1}^j,\omega_p^r\right)\right)\,.\tag{2}$$
The only difference between (1) and (2) is that (2) handles the trivial case $m=0$, while (1) does not.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand how this solution works.

Comment: My post is not a solution per se.  I wanted to make this as a comment on Jack D'Aurizio's answer, but commenting under his answer was not an option.  For a real solution, Ross Millikan already gave that to you.